# Bad Request while runnging wordcount example

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am new to google cloud dataflow. I setup everything on my windows machine and when i tried to run wordcount example using below command:

mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.nyt.dataflowPoc.WordCount -Dexec.args="--project=cdfpoc-1264 --stagingLocation=gs://poc-location/staging --runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner --output=gs://poc-location"

and it gave me below error.

Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid Value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Value"
}

I looked at other posts and it said that i need to give projectID which shouuld be alpha numberic.I am already giving that but still same error.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

-Kapil

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from:

```
--output=gs://poc-location
```

As such you are only specifying a bucket. WordCount actually interprets this as a prefix for your output, and tries to write the file gs://poc-location-00000-of-00001. Since this bucket does not exist you get an error.
Your pipeline will run fine with:

```
--output=gs://poc-location/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. I was giving both staging and output location. When I digged more into the code , I found that only one of them was needed. So when I removed --output parameter , I got actual output and i could see results at storage location specified.

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: Generally speaking, it should be fine to specify both `stagingLocation` and `output` pipeline option. If output is not specified, it will default to `gs://your-staging-location/counts.txt`. That said, you should be able to specify any other Google Cloud Storage location, and shouldn't see any issues.